# Perl: String to anonymous array?

Tags: string, perl, transform, anonymous-arrays

***SOLVED ALREADY*** --> See edit 7

At this moment I'm fairly new on Perl, and trying to modify part of an existing page (in Wonderdesk).
The way the page works, is that it gets the information from the GET url and parses it to an SQL query.

Since this is part of a much larger system, I'm not able to modify the coding around it, and have to solve it in this script.

A working test I performed:

```
$input->{help_id} = ['33450','31976'];
```

When running this, the query that is being build returns something as

> select * from table where help_id in(33450,31976)

The  part of my code that does not work as expected:

```
my $callIDs = '33450,31450';
my @callIDs = split(/,/,$callIDs);
my $callIDsearch = \@callIDs;
$input->{help_id} = $callIDsearch;
```

When running this, the query that is being build returns something as

> select * from table where help_id = '33450,31976'

I've tried to debug it, and used Data::Dumper to get the result of $callIDsearch, which appears as [33450, 31450] in my browser.

Can someone give me a hint on how to transform from '123,456' into ['123', '456']?

With kind regards,
Marcel

--===--

Edit:

As requested, minimal code piece that works:

```
$input->{help_id} = ['123','456']
```

Code that does not work:

```
$str = '123,456';
@ids = split(/,/,$str);
$input->{help_id} = \@ids;
```

--===--

Edit 2:

Source of the question:
The following part of the code is responsible for getting the correct information from the database:

```
my $input = $IN->get_hash;
my $db = $DB->table('help_desk');
foreach (keys %$input){
    if (/^corr/ and !/-opt$/ and $input->{$_} or $input->{keyword}){
        $db = $DB->table('help_desk','correspondence');
        $input->{rs} = 'DISTINCT help_id,help_name,help_email,help_datetime,help_subject,help_website,help_category,
                       help_priority,help_status,help_emergency_flag,help_cus_id_fk,help_tech,help_attach';
       $input->{left_join} = 1;
        last;
    }
}

# Do the search
my $sth  = $db->query_sth($input);
my $hits = $db->hits;
```

Now instead of being able to provide a single parameter help_id, I want to be able to provide multiple parameters.

--===--

Edit 3:

query_sth is either of the following two, have not been able to find it out yet:

```
$COMPILE{query} = __LINE__ . <<'END_OF_SUB';
sub query {
# -----------------------------------------------------------
# $obj->query($HASH or $CGI);
# ----------------------------
#   Performs a query based on the options in the hash.
#   $HASH can be a hash ref, hash or CGI object.
#
#   Returns the result of a query as fetchall_arrayref.
#
    my $self = shift;
    my $sth = $self->_query(@_) or return;
    return $sth->fetchall_arrayref;
}
END_OF_SUB

$COMPILE{query_sth} = __LINE__ . <<'END_OF_SUB';
sub query_sth {
# -----------------------------------------------------------
# $obj->query_sth($HASH or $CGI);
# --------------------------------
# Same as query but returns the sth object.
#
    shift->_query(@_)
}
END_OF_SUB
```

Or

```
$COMPILE{query} = __LINE__ . <<'END_OF_SUB';
sub query {
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# Just performs the query and returns a fetchall.
#
    return shift->_query(@_)->fetchall_arrayref;
}
END_OF_SUB

$COMPILE{query_sth} = __LINE__ . <<'END_OF_SUB';
sub query_sth {
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# Just performs the query and returns an active sth.
#
    return shift->_query(@_);
}
END_OF_SUB
```

--===--

Edit 4: _query

```
$COMPILE{_query} = __LINE__ . <<'END_OF_SUB';
sub _query {
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# Parses the input, and runs a select based on input.
#
    my $self = shift;
    my $opts = $self->common_param(@_) or return $self->fatal(BADARGS => 'Usage: $obj->insert(HASH or HASH_REF or CGI) only.');
    $self->name or return $self->fatal('NOTABLE');
# Clear errors.
    $self->{_error} = [];

# Strip out values that are empty or blank (as query is generally derived from
# cgi input).
my %input = map { $_ => $opts->{$_} } grep { defined $opts->{$_} and $opts->{$_} !~ /^\s*$/ } keys %$opts;
    $opts = \%input;

# If build_query_cond returns a GT::SQL::Search object, then we are done.
    my $cond = $self->build_query_cond($opts, $self->{schema}->{cols});

    if ( ( ref $cond ) =~ /(?:DBI::st|::STH)$/i ) {
        return $cond;
    }

# If we have a callback, then we get all the results as a hash, send them
# to the callback, and then do the regular query on the remaining set.
    if (defined $opts->{callback} and (ref $opts->{callback} eq 'CODE')) {
        my $pk  = $self->{schema}->{pk}->[0];
        my $sth = $self->select($pk, $cond) or return;
        my %res = map { $_ => 1 } $sth->fetchall_list;
        my $new_results = $opts->{callback}->($self, \%res);
        $cond = GT::SQL::Condition->new($pk, 'IN', [keys %$new_results]);
    }

# Set the limit clause, defaults to 25, set to -1 for none.
    my $in = $self->_get_search_opts($opts);
    my $offset   = ($in->{nh} - 1) * $in->{mh};
    $self->select_options("ORDER BY $in->{sb} $in->{so}") if ($in->{sb});
    $self->select_options("LIMIT $in->{mh} OFFSET $offset") unless $in->{mh} == -1;

# Now do the select.
    my @sel = ();
    if ($cond)                  { push @sel, $cond }
    if ($opts->{rs} and $cond)  { push @sel, $opts->{rs} }
    my $sth = $self->select(@sel) or return;

    return $sth;
}
END_OF_SUB
```

--===--

Edit 5: I've uploaded the SQL module that is used:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yz0bq8ch8kdgyl6/SQL.zip

--===--

Edit 6:

On request, the dumps (trimmed to only include the sections for help_id):

The result of the modification in Base.pm for the non-working code:

```
$VAR1 = [
          33450,
          31450
        ];
```

The result of the modification in Condition.pm for the non-working code:

```
$VAR1 = [
          "help_id",
          "IN",
          [
            33450,
            31450
          ]
        ];
$VAR1 = [
      "cus_username",
      "=",
      "Someone"
    ];
$VAR1 = [
          "help_id",
          "=",
          "33450,31450"
        ];
```

The result for the modification in Base.pm for the working code:

```
$VAR1 = [
          33450,
          31976
        ];
```

The result for the modification in Condition.pm for the working code:

```
$VAR1 = [
          "help_id",
          "IN",
          [
            33450,
            31976
          ]
        ];
```

It looks as if the value gets changed afterwards somehow :S
All I changed for the working/non-working code was to replace:

```
$input->{help_id} = ['33450','31976'];
```

With:

```
$input->{help_id} = [ split(/,/,'33450,31450') ];
```

--===--

Edit 7:

After reading all the tips, I decided to start over and found that by writing some logs to files, I could break down into the issue with more details.

I'm still not sure why, but it now works, using the same methods as before. I think it's a typo/glitch/bug in my code somewhere..

Sorry to have bothered you all, but I still recommend the points to go to amon due to his tips providing the breakthrough.

Comment: The problem is somewhere else, because the two code snippets you have shown are equivalent. This code works. But how is the SQL being created?

Comment: That is what I thought as well, but if the code is equivalent, then why  isn't the result, if I'm not changing the function that is being called?

Comment: The problem is between creating the arrayref and printing out the SQL, and we need to see that part. Could you show a *complete but minimal* piece of code that shows that one snippet works and the other does not? See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for tips.

Comment: I've added (see Edit 2) the original minimal source that is used to get the results. If you want the code behind, I have to look it up after lunch.

Comment: I think that the part we need to see is the part where the `query_sth` is declared

Comment: Ok, I meant minimal code that demonstrates the actual problem. What module are you using to interface with the database? This isn't `DBI`…

Comment: The environment is Wonderdesk. I'm not sure what they are using, but I added the declaration of query_sth to the question.

Comment: It's like a treasure hunt :) now we're looking for `_query`

Comment: Apologies :P I'm not really into Perl yet, and I'm trying to understand the code as I read it. I've added the part of _query, but I'm afraid this is not the last of the code you need. I'm trying to upload a zip file with the SQL module.

Comment: Uploaded the SQL module to https://www.dropbox.com/s/yz0bq8ch8kdgyl6/SQL.zip

Comment: @Master-Guy one last addition if you can. I'd like to see the code in which you actually call the query from your own script. The module is huge.

Comment: The part of the page called is uploaded to https://www.dropbox.com/s/ozwcddq9z48na1m/module.txt and it gets parsed into an HTML file.

Comment: @Master-Guy Sorry but I can't figure it out. Only thing I can think that may help is that you print some Data::Dumper output of `$input` right before your `my $sth  = $db->query_sth($input);` line. Probably of both cases, one that works, one that doesn't work. The whole thing seems crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an answer, but I have found a few critical points where we need to know what is going on.

In `build_query_cond` (`Base.pm` line 528), an array argument will be transformed into an `key in (...)` relation:

```
if (ref($opts->{$field}) eq 'ARRAY' ) {
    my $add = [];
    for ( @{$opts->{$field}} ) {
        next if !defined( $_ ) or !length( $_ ) or !/\S/;
        push @$add, $_;
    }
    if ( @$add ) {
        push @ins, [$field, 'IN', $add];
    }
}
```

Interesting bit in `sql` (`Condition.pm` line 181). Even if there is an arrayref, an `IN` test will be simplified to an `=` test if it contains only a single element.

```
if (uc $op eq 'IN' || $op eq '=' and ref $val eq 'ARRAY') {
    if (@$val > 1) {
        $op = 'IN';
        $val = '('
            . join(',' => map !length || /\D/ ? quote($_) : $_, @$val)
            . ')';
    }
    elsif (@$val == 0) {
        ($col, $op, $val) = (qw(1 = 0));
    }
    else {
        $op  = '=';
        $val = quote($val->[0]);
    }
    push @output, "$col $op $val";
}
```

Before these two conditions, it would be interesting to insert the following code:

```
Carp::cluck(Data::Dumper::Dump(...));
```

where `...` is `$opts->{$field}` in the first snippet or `$cond` in the second snippet. The resulting stack trace would allow us to find all subroutines which could have modified the value. For this to work, the following code has to be placed in your main script before starting the query:

```
use Carp ();
use Data::Dumper;

$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;  # escape special characters
```

Once the code has been modified like this, run both the working and not-working code, and print out the resulting query with

```
print Dumper($result);
```

So for each of your code snippets, we should get two stack traces and one resulting SQL query.

Comment: From edit 7:

After reading all the tips, I decided to start over and found that by writing some logs to files, I could break down into the issue with more details.

I'm still not sure why, but it now works, using the same methods as before. I think it's a typo/glitch/bug in my code somewhere..

Sorry to have bothered you all, but I still recommend the points to go to amon due to his tips providing the breakthrough.

Answer (score 1):

A shot in the dark... there's a temporary array `@callIDs` created by this code:

```
my @callIDs = split(/,/,$callIDs);
my $callIDsearch = \@callIDs;
$input->{help_id} = $callIDsearch;
```

If some other part of your code modifies `@callIDs`, even *after* it's been assigned to `$input->{help_id}`, that could cause problems. Of course the fact that it's a lexical (`my`) variable means that any such changes to `@callIDs` are probably "nearby".

You could eliminate the named temporary array by doing the split like this:

```
$input->{help_id} = [ split(/,/,$callIDs) ];
```

Comment: I really think that this must be what's happening.  I'm giving a +1 for that reason.  None of the other theories really hold water for me.

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work either, thanks for the suggestion though :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly why this is happening. It seems that your query builder needs an arrayref of strings. You can use `map` to do that

```
my $callIDs = '33450,31450';
my @callIDs = map {$_*1} split(/,/,$callIDs);
$input->{help_id} = \@callIDs;
```

Comment: `split` *always* returns a string. If we dump the elements (with Devel::Peek), we see that the arrayref only contains `PV`s (string scalars). It's only the Data::Dumper module that sees that the string *looks* like a number, and formats it accordingly. This code works just fine, even without `map`. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: the split function already returns a string, so no need to put the anonymous variable in a string. you should stringify the single quotes. that is: ... map { qq{'$_'} } split...

Comment: Dumper does return the correct value: $VAR1 = [ '33450', '31450' ];, but it still doesn't work as expected

Comment: @Master-Guy: does this work? `$input->{help_id} = [123,456]` . Maybe it actually needs an array ref of ints? See my edited answer

Comment: Parsing with either single quotes or no quotes returns the same result

Comment: @amon `Data::Dumper` even behaves differently depending whether the XS or pure perl dumper is used. Try out `Useperl`.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work

```
my $callIDs = '33450,31450';
$input->{help_id} = [split ",", $callIDs];
```

If your code somehow detect your data is number you can use

```
my $callIDs = '33450,31450';
$input->{help_id} = [map 0+$_, split ',', $callIDs];
```

If it somehow become number and you need string instead which should not in this case but advice for future work:

```
my $callIDs = '33450,31450';
$input->{help_id} = [map ''.$_, split ',', $callIDs];
```